# How to convert JSON object to markdown using pypandoc without writing to file?

Tags: python, json, markdown, format-conversion, pypandoc

I am trying to take a response from an API that reports back a JSON object and convert that to a markdown output to present it in a more readable format. I am attempting to use pypandoc to do this and I am having a very time figuring out how to get it to work.

I would expect the following to work based on the documentation from pandoc but the pypandoc docs and examples are scarce.

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois

obj = IPWhois('74.125.225.229')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
print(pypandoc.convert_text(results, 'json', 'md'))



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6a5e630f5495> in <module>()
      4 obj = IPWhois('74.125.225.229')
      5 results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
----> 6 print(pypandoc.convert_text(results, 'json', 'md'))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py in convert_text(source, to, format, extra_args, encoding, outputfile, filters)
    101     source = _as_unicode(source, encoding)
    102     return _convert_input(source, format, 'string', to, extra_args=extra_args,
--> 103                           outputfile=outputfile, filters=filters)
    104 
    105 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py in _convert_input(source, format, input_type, to, extra_args, outputfile, filters)
    303 
    304     try:
--> 305         source = cast_bytes(source, encoding='utf-8')
    306     except (UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
    307         # assume that it is already a utf-8 encoded string

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\py3compat.py in cast_bytes(s, encoding)
     37     # bytes == str on py2.7 -> always encode on py2
     38     if not isinstance(s, bytes):
---> 39         return _encode(s, encoding)
     40     return s
     41 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\py3compat.py in _encode(u, encoding)
     25 def _encode(u, encoding=None):
     26     encoding = encoding or _DEFAULT_ENCODING
---> 27     return u.encode(encoding)
     28 
     29 

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

If anyone knows a better way to convert this without writing it down to a file I would be very appreciative if you shared it.

writing to and reading from file version:

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
from pprint import pprint
import json, pypandoc

obj = IPWhois('74.125.225.229')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
pprint(results)
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results, outfile)
output = pypandoc.convert_file('data.json', to='json', format='md',outputfile="data.md")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: I should be able to do this in memory

Please show your code doing it **to/from File**.
It should be able to do it in Memory using a `StringIO` object.

`results` is of Type `dict`, change to `str` using `json.dumps(...` should be the same as reading from file:

```
print(pypandoc.convert_text(json.dumps(results), 'json', 'md'))
```

---

> **Question**: I would expect the following to work based on the documentation from pandoc
>   ... convert that to ... in a more readable format.

You have to convert it by your own, either to `md` or `HTML`.
It's the same effort as the following example:

> [Convert JSON to PDF with Python and xtopdf](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578979-convert-json-to-pdf-with-python-and-xtopdf/)
>
> This recipe show the basic steps needed to convert JSON input to PDF output, using Python and xtopdf,
>   a PDF creation toolkit. xtopdf is itself written in Python, and uses the ReportLab toolkit internally.

Comment: pypandoc being a wrapper for pandoc should have access to all of the functionality of pandoc which clearly shows that is is capable of the conversion here: http://pandoc.org/index.html

I can additionally get it to convert if I write the info to a file, convert the file and read it back into memory, however, I should be able to do this in memory I just cant seem to figure out how.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyandoc/ shows  
Formats available:  
asciidoc  
beamer  
commonmark  
context  
docbook  
doc- x  
dokuwiki  
dzslides  
epub  
epub3  
fb2  
haddock  
html  
html5  
icml  
json (pandoc’s AST)  
latex  
man  
markdown  
markdown_github  
markdown_mmd  
markdown_phpextra  
markdown_strict  
mediawiki  
native  
odt  
opendocument  
opml  
org  
pdf  
plain  
revealjs  
rst  
rtf  
s5,  
slideous  
slidy  
texinfo  
textile  
 and pandoc shows it here  
http://pandoc.org/diagram.jpg

Comment: Looks like I wasn't paying great attention to the output when writing to a file.  It is modifying the data, but it's not turning it to actual markdown even with writing it to a file. If I had to guess its converted to pandoc AST maybe?

Comment: THANKS! that's exactly what I was missing!