# Convert nested lists from JSON string to MD string using pypandoc

Tags: python, json, markdown, converters, pypandoc

### Foreword

I am totally aware that converting JSON (complex data structure) to MD (markup language) is probably an ill defined concept as they are not able to represent the same things. Anyway I think that it can be done for simple structure such as nested list.

There are very few documentation on `pypandoc` and such a conversion, anyway I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768989/how-to-convert-json-object-to-markdown-using-pypandoc-without-writing-to-file) with a similar question and I wondered it could be achieved but I could not make it work as expected.

#### MCVE

Let's say I want to convert some simple JSON nested lists into a MD nested lists. Here is my MCVE

```
import json
import pypandoc

items = [
    "Item A",
    "Item B",
    "Item C", ["Sub Item C.1", "Sub Item C.2", "Sub Item C.3"],
    "Item D", ["Sub Item D.1", "Sub Item D.2"],
    "Item E"
]

result = pypandoc.convert_text(json.dumps(items), to="json", format="md")
```

Which obviously returns a JSON string:

```
'{"pandoc-api-version":[1,22,2,1],"meta":{},"blocks":[{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"["},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"A"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"B"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"C:"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"["},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Sub"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"C.1"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Sub"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"C.2"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Sub"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"C.3"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":"],"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"D"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"["},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Sub"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"D.1"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":","},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Sub"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"D.2"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":"],"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Quoted","c":[{"t":"DoubleQuote"},[{"t":"Str","c":"Item"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"E"}]]},{"t":"Str","c":"]"}]}]}\r\n'
```

It seems to be an internal representation of what need to be encoded but this is noway MD.

But I was expecting this output:

```
 - Item A
 - Item B
 - Item C
   - Sub Item C.1
   - Sub Item C.2
   - Sub Item C.3
 - Item D
   - Sub Item D.1
   - Sub Item D.2
 - Item E
```

What is weird it the confusing terminology for switch `to` and `format` that seems to indicate the conversion is from MD to JSON.

When configuring the call in the opposite order, it fails miserably:

```
result = pypandoc.convert_text(json.dumps(items), format="json", to="md")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7128/3771718373.py in <module>
----> 1 result = pypandoc.convert_text(json.dumps(items), format="json", to="md")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py in convert_text(source, to, format, extra_args, encoding, outputfile, filters, verify_format, sandbox, cworkdir)
     91     """
     92     source = _as_unicode(source, encoding)
---> 93     return _convert_input(source, format, 'string', to, extra_args=extra_args,
     94                           outputfile=outputfile, filters=filters,
     95                           verify_format=verify_format, sandbox=sandbox,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py in _convert_input(source, format, input_type, to, extra_args, outputfile, filters, verify_format, sandbox, cworkdir)
    416     # check that pandoc returned successfully
    417     if p.returncode != 0:
--> 418         raise RuntimeError(
    419             'Pandoc died with exitcode "%s" during conversion: %s' % (p.returncode, stderr)
    420         )

RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "64" during conversion: JSON parse error: Error in $: mempty
```

So I am wondering is it possible to convert JSON to MD using `pypandoc`?

What I am supposed to do with the JSON returned in the first example, is it an internal `pandoc` representation that can indeed be converted to MD afterward ?
What am I missing to achieve this conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

While not answering directly the question it seems the expected output can be achieved by using `snakemd`:

```
import snakemd

items = snakemd.MDList([
    "Item A",
    "Item B",
    "Item C:", snakemd.MDList(["Sub Item C.1", "Sub Item C.2", "Sub Item C.3"]),
    "Item D", snakemd.MDList(["Sub Item D.1", "Sub Item D.2"]),
    "Item E"
])

items.render()
```

Which returns:

```
- Item A
- Item B
- Item C:
  - Sub Item C.1
  - Sub Item C.2
  - Sub Item C.3
- Item D
  - Sub Item D.1
  - Sub Item D.2
- Item E
```

But this does not answer to the original question.